# English: "$y$ is at least $2$ units from $\pi$" to symbolic inequality.

Tags: inequality, translation-request

The title says it all. I was hoping the community could check me on my understanding of translating the following sentence to an inequality:

```
y is at least 2 units from pi
```

I'm thinking the following inequality is an accurate translation:

[edited]
$$
|y-\pi|\ge2
$$

Comment: Almost. You have it the wrong way round.

Comment: @TonyK I'm struggling with the LaTeX. Is it rendering on your end?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why it's not rendering on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Distance **at least** 2 means the difference between the numbers is 2 or larger.

Suppose $y > \pi$, then we would translate the sentence to $y - \pi \geq 2$.

Suppose $\pi > y$, then we would translate the sentence to $\pi - y \geq 2$ or equivalently $-(y - \pi) \geq 2$.

The two expressions can be joined together as: $$|y - \pi| \geq 2$$

In short, we can consider $|a-b|$ as a distance function between the values $a$ and $b$.